# Cannot register cron job because it is defined in a non static provider - NestJS

Tags: node.js, cron, nestjs

I am creating a worker that will perform a db operation timely. When I define my  `private readonly validationRuleRepository: ValidationRulesRepository,`, it seems to not register the cron.

ValidationRulesRepository's scope is `Scope.DEFAULT` as well.

```
@Injectable({ scope: Scope.DEFAULT })
export class RulesCleanupWorker {
    private readonly logger: Logger = new Logger(RulesCleanupWorker.name);

    public constructor(
        private readonly validationRuleRepository: ValidationRulesRepository,
    ) { }

    @Cron(CronExpression.EVERY_30_SECONDS)
    public async handleCron(): Promise<void> {
        this.logger.debug('Starting to delete version 00 validation rules');
        // await this.validationRuleRepository.deleteVersion00Rules();
        this.logger.debug('ended clean up activity');
    }
}
```

The cronjob doesn't execute and it's not registered. I see this warning in logs:

```
[Nest] 21620  - 05/29/2023, 2:01:22 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/api/vr-package/:id/copy-rules, POST} (version: 1) route +1ms
[Nest] 21620  - 05/29/2023, 2:01:22 PM    WARN [Scheduler] Cannot register cron job "RulesCleanupWorker@handleCron" because it is defined in a non static provider.
[Nest] 21620  - 05/29/2023, 2:01:22 PM     LOG [NestApplication] Nest application successfully started +0ms
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your `ValidationRulesRepository` injects a `REQUEST` scoped provider. If not the repository, then possibly the TypeORM module's configuration. Whether you specific `scope: Scope.DEFAULT` or not doesn't change the scope if you end up injecting a `REQUEST` scoped provider into it, or into one of its dependencies

Comment: It's scoped as default and I have passed it in  APP_PROVIDERS `@Module({
  imports: [...APP_IMPORTS, ScheduleModule.forRoot()],
  controllers: [...APP_CONTROLLERS],
  providers: [...APP_PROVIDERS],
})`

Comment: What are the injections that `ValidationRulesRepository` has? What about its dependencies? What about your `DatabaseMoudle` (depending on what that is)

Comment: Knex.js builder  `public constructor(@Inject(SQL_CONNECTION) private readonly knex: Knex) {
    super(knex, VR_TABLES.VALIDATION_RULES);
  }`

Comment: What's the provider definition for `SQL_CONNECTION` look like?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved issue by removing the REQUEST in all services directly or indirectly used by cronjobs, which is imported from the nestjs/common, if u need the request object in a service then pass it from controller to required service.
in nestjs, pass like below

```
@Patch('disputed-lecture/:id/action')
async disputedLectureAction(
    @Req() req: RequestIncludingUser,
    @Param('id', ParseIntPipe) id: number,
    @Body() dto: DisputedLecturesActionDto,
) {
    return await this.paymentService.disputedLectureAction(
        id,
        req?.user?.userId,
        dto,
    );
}
```